# Can a node publish different types on one topic?

Tags: ros, node, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and just started studying. I am stuck with using custom message types. I would like to know is it possible to publish two different data type to single topic? Or do we need to publish separately?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251319/can-a-node-publish-different-types-on-one-topic?/) by [Edu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28964/edu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-01-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akhilesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28821/akhilesh/) on 2017-01-05**:
Hi, you can publish even more than two data types but it depends on what you want to send.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2017-01-05**:
their is no need to publish two types of msgs from single topic, just make another publisher its easy, any number of msgs u can publish, but from single topic i'm hearing first time.

**Comment by [Akhilesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28821/akhilesh/) on 2017-01-06**:
if you advertise a topic like ***node.advertise("camera_info", 1);*** , so in [CameraInfo](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) class, there is more than one data types are available like ***uint32, string*** etc.

**Comment by [Kenn](https://answers.ros.org/users/31209/kenn/) on 2017-07-17**:
HI, did you find a solution?

**Comment by [Akhilesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28821/akhilesh/) on 2017-07-18**:
Can you specify what exactly you want to publish? Or add some piece of code to understand the need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you have to publish it separately.
Why would you want to publish in the same topic? If you explain what you are trying to accomplish, maybe we can propose a solution.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28964/edu/) on 2017-01-05**:
Thank you !!! :)

**Comment by [Kenn](https://answers.ros.org/users/31209/kenn/) on 2017-07-17**:
Hi, I am trying to accomplish something similar, can you take a look at my question? Thanks.